# django orm join without foiriegn key

Tags: orm, django-queryset, django-orm

Setup

- Django 2.0.2
- MariaDB 10.2
- Windows Server 2012

**models.py**

```
class Postreply(models.Model):
    replyuid = models.BigAutoField(db_column='ReplyUID', primary_key=True)
    postuid = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='PostUID')
    useruid = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='UserUID')
    content = models.TextField(db_column='Content')
    registerdate = models.DateTimeField(
        db_column='RegisterDate', default=datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"))

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'postreply'

class Postinfo(models.Model):
    postuid = models.BigAutoField(db_column='PostUID', primary_key=True)
    useruid = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='UserUID')
    content = models.TextField(db_column='Content')
    replycount = models.IntegerField(db_column='ReplyCount', default=0)
    registerdate = models.DateTimeField(
            db_column='RegisterDate', default=datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"))

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'postinfo'

class Userinfo(models.Model):
    useruid = models.BigAutoField(db_column='UserUID', primary_key=True)
    useremail = models.CharField(
        db_column='UserEmail', unique=True, max_length=100)
    userpassword = models.CharField(db_column='UserPassword', max_length=128)
    passwordsalt = models.CharField(db_column='PasswordSalt', max_length=128)
    usersex = models.IntegerField(db_column='UserSex')
    userage = models.IntegerField(db_column='UserAge')
    username = models.CharField(
        db_column='UserName', max_length=100, default=0)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'userinfo'
```

I want filter the `postreply` table by the `postuid` field to 
and get `userinfo` instance by useruid in fitered postreply

if postinfo ex)

```
              postuid =3
```

postreply ex)

```
              postuid = 3 useruid =21 replyuid= 1
              postuid = 3 useruid =22 replyuid= 2
              postuid = 3 useruid =21 replyuid= 3
              postuid = 2 useruid =21 replyuid= 4
              postuid = 3 useruid =33 replyuid= 5
```

userinfo ex)

```
              useruid = 21 username = 'A'
              useruid = 22 username = 'B'
              useruid = 33 username = 'C'
```

if put postuid = 3 i want this

```
postuid = 3 useruid =21 replyuid= 1 username = 'A'
postuid = 3 useruid =22 replyuid= 2 username = 'B'
postuid = 3 useruid =21 replyuid= 3 username = 'A'
postuid = 3 useruid =33 replyuid= 5 username = 'C'
```

how to this

Answer (score 0):

By using the [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) method you extract a list of just the relevant user ids and then use that to filter the `Userinfo`s based on that list, like so:

```py
chosen_id = 3
user_ids = Postreply.objects.filter(postuid=chosen_id).values_list('useruid')
users = Userinfo.objects.filter(userid__in=user_ids)
```